# Converting a MySQL Subquery to a JOIN for performance

Tags: mysql

I took a look at my old accounting system, and it seems that performance is taking a role in the daily labor of the employees using it. So, I discovered that using a subquery was the problem, I've been reading, testing and, it seems that using a JOIN is like 100x faster as the data that we have in our Databases is huge now.

How do I can convert this subquery into a JOIN?

> I'm seeking for help because I'm trying, but I'm being unable to do it, and I'm starting to think that this is not possible.

```
$sql = "SELECT  orders.order_id, orders.order_time, orders.order_user,
        orders.payment_state, orders.order_state, orders.area_name,
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  order_item
            WHERE  order_item.order_id = orders.order_id
        ) AS items_number
        FROM  orders
        WHERE  orders.order_state = 1
        AND  order_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW()";
```

Being specific, the data we are retrieving here is all the rows created in the last year from the orders table **AND** the number of items purchased in each order, which is called from the subquery as items_number from order_item table **WHERE** order_id is equal in each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do what another Answer suggests -- it involves the "explode-implode", which is even slower.

I would start by seeing if this helped much:

```
 orders:  INDEX(order_state, order_time)
```

Your correlated subquery is not necessarily inefficient *in this case*.  (That 100X quote is based on too few examples to be trustworthy.)

This avoids the explode-implode and turns the subquery into a "derived table" (which is similar) but it needs to be executed only once.

```
SELECT  o.order_id, o.order_time, o.order_user,
        o.payment_state, o.order_state, o.area_name,
        i.items_number
    FROM ( SELECT order_id,
                  COUNT(*) AS items_number
               FROM order_item
               GROUP BY order_id ) AS i
    JOIN orders AS o  ON o.order_id = i.order_id
    WHERE  order_state = 1
      AND  order_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 365 DAY
```

If you need "zero" values for orders without items, a minor change can achieve that; let me know.

The index above is needed here.  Also, if you don't already have `order_id` indexed in `order_item, add that.

Comment: @RickJames, nice I've been testing the query and it's superior from the INNER JOIN one (100 - 200ms faster). Got unnoticed items_number from select, updating question an answers...

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be like so:

```
SELECT ord.order_id, ord.orden_time, ord.orden_user, ord.payment_state, ord.order_state,
       ord.area_name, COUNT(itm.item_id) AS items_number
  FROM orders ord INNER JOIN order_item itm ON ord.order_id = itm.order_id
 WHERE ord.order_state = 1
   and ord.order_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW()
 GROUP BY ord.order_id, ord.orden_time, ord.orden_user, ord.payment_state, ord.order_state,
          ord.area_name
```

This query assumes that every `orders` record will contain a minimum of one `order_item` record, which makes sense. Be sure to change `item_id` to whatever the primary key is for the `order_item` table.

As an aside, if you would like your `BETWEEN` statement to be a little more fixed in time, you might want to use `DATE_FORMAT()` to ensure the start time is always `00:00:00` rather than the time of day when the query was run:

```
and ord.order_time BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND NOW()
```